# ASINetworkQueue inside NSOperation error saving Core Data

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I want to use the ASINetworkQueue inside an NSOperation. This works great and makes no problem. What fails is saving Core Data. I set up a new NSManagedObjectContext for this Operation like it is told in the docs.

I think that the problem is that I save the data when the ASINetworkQueue finishes and delegate selector is called. Because the delegates are called on the mainThread, the save message fails.

Can this be the problem and does anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the PerformSelectorOnMainThread method right (to merge the changes from the new instantiated ManagedObjectContext)?

I do something like this in my Operations (ctx is my instantiated MOC):

First register for notifications:

```
// Register context with the notification center
        NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 

        [nc addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) 
                   name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                 object:ctx];
```

Then when you need to save the context:

```
if ([ctx hasChanges]) {
            error = nil;

            // Save the context.
            if (![ctx save:&error])
            {
                // Do something with the error
            }

            // Clear out the scratchpad
            [ctx reset];

        }
```

And then the method that does the merging with the main MOC:

```
- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  

    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
    [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) 
                                  withObject:notification
                               waitUntilDone:NO];
    // NSLog(@"Merged Changes");
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I use this, but I think it crashes because the delegates are called on the mainThread so if I save my separate created context, I get an error because it's not saved on the separate thread. This is my suggestion but maybe this is not the problem.

Comment: You can't instantiate the ASINetworkQueue inside the NSOperation and handle the delegate method there also?  I do this same kind of thing (although just using ASIHttpRequest) and handle the delegate method inside the NSOperation and it works fine.